# After merging, replace resulting NA values with 0, keeping pre-existing NAs

Tags: r, merge

When merging two data frames, how can I set the `NA` values resulting from the merge to 0, while leaving the pre-existing `NA` values as `NA`?

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- fread("
TYPE
A
B
C
")

df2 <- fread("
   TYPE Num Dollar
      A  NA 215.77
      B  11 NA
")

merge(df1, df2, all.x = T)
```

Actual output:

```
   TYPE Num Dollar
1:    A  NA 215.77
2:    B  11     NA
3:    C  NA     NA
```

Desired output:

```
   TYPE Num Dollar
1:    A  NA 215.77
2:    B  11     NA
3:    C   0      0
```

Edit: Here's a better example showing why you can't rely on indexes in the more general case

```
df1 <- fread("
TYPE
A
B
C
", data.table = F)

df2 <- fread("
   TYPE Num Dollar
      A  NA 215.77
      C  11 NA
", data.table = F)

merge(df1, df2, all.x = T)
#   TYPE Num Dollar
# 1    A  NA 215.77
# 2    B  NA     NA
# 3    C  11     NA
inx <- which(is.na(df2), arr.ind = TRUE)
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, all.x = T)
df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0
df3[inx] <- NA
df3
#   TYPE Num Dollar
# 1    A  NA 215.77
# 2    B   0     NA
# 3    C  11   0.00
```

Edit: Both Rui Barradas and akrun's answers work. For lack of any other differentiating factor, I accepted Rui's answer since it works on `data.frame`s as well as `data.table`s

Comment: Just do `df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Check the desired output. This does not match.

Comment: I think you may have to change the `NA` at the initial dataset to something like `-999` and then do the change after the merge i.e. `for(j in 2:3) set(df2, i= which(is.na(df2[[j]])), j = j, -999)`

Comment: OK, sorry, misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there are simpler ways but the following will do it.

**Note:**
The original code was completely revised in order to cope with the possibility stated in the OP's comment in the quote.

> This is good, but only works if the indexes match. Consider    the
>   case when instead of C missing, B is missing from df2.    Then the
>   rows in df3 coming from df2 have indexes 1 and 3,    while in df2 they
>   have indexes 1 and 2

The new code solves both cases, so I put it in a function.

```
library(data.table)

fun <- function(DF1, DF2){
  res <- merge(DF1, DF2, all.x = T, by = 'TYPE')
  inx <- which(!(DF1$TYPE %in% DF2$TYPE))
  res[inx, which(is.na(res[inx, ]))] <- 0
  res
}

fun(df1, df2)
#   TYPE Num Dollar
#1:    A  NA 215.77
#2:    B  11     NA
#3:    C   0   0.00

fun(df1, df3)
#   TYPE Num Dollar
#1:    A  NA 215.77
#2:    B   0   0.00
#3:    C  11     NA
```

**Test data.**

`df1` and `df2` are the data.frames in the question, `df3` is the df in the OP's comment.

```
df1 <- fread("
TYPE
A
B
C
")

df2 <- fread("
   TYPE Num Dollar
             A  NA 215.77
             B  11 NA
             ")

df3 <- fread("
   TYPE Num Dollar
      A  NA 215.77
      C  11 NA
")
```

Comment: This is good, but only works if the indexes match. Consider the case when instead of `C` missing, `B` is missing from `df2`. Then the rows in `df3` coming from `df2` have indexes 1 and 3, while in `df2` they have indexes 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Rui Barradas solution, we could create a flag variable in the second dataset and change the output of `merge`

```
out <- merge(df1, df2[, flag := TRUE], all.x = TRUE)
nm1 <- c("Num", "Dollar")
for(j in nm1) set(out, i = which(is.na(out$flag)), j=j, value = 0)
out[, flag := NULL][]
#   TYPE Num Dollar
#1:    A  NA 215.77
#2:    B  11     NA
#3:    C   0   0.00
```

---

Or using join

```
out <- copy(df1)
out[df2, c(nm1, 'flag') := c(mget(nm1), list(TRUE)), on = .(TYPE)]
```

and then do the replacement of NA to 0 as above